# Download file from public storage in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-filesystem

I am trying to download a file stored in `

> "storage/app/public/uploaded_documents/"

my code is below

```
<a href="{{storage_path()}}/app/public/uploaded_documents/{{$Publications->dataset_file}}" download>
                                    <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

But when i click the download link the file doesn't get dowloaded instead it shows "network error"
What is the problem and how to solve

`

Comment: try to use a different browser and check if you can download

Comment: nope it dosent work

Comment: try to inspect and see the path rendered in th browser

Comment: "D:\dsse\dsse\laravel\blog\storage\app/public/uploaded_documents/1499615676.pdf" this the path in href and works fine if i open this path in new tab